# Как получить данные из другого столбца той же строки в peewee

Tags: python, peewee

У меня есть модель:

```
class token(Model):
token = CharField() 
is_teacher = BooleanField() 
class Meta:
    database = db
```

И мне нужно по значению token найти полуить значение *is_teacher*. Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
def CheckTokenTeacher(token_name):
tokens = token.select().where(token.token==token_name)
if len(tokens) is 1:
    return tokens[0].is_teacher
else:
    return 0
```

Но VS Code сообщает, что

> Assigning to function call which doesn't return

Как мне решить эту ошибку и получить значение *is_teacher* для *token*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это была достаточно глупая ошибка, достаточно было добавить метод .get() . Например:

```
token.select().where(token.token==token_name).get()
```

или

```
token.get().where(token.token==token_name)
```